# nl2br doesn't work with text from the database

Tags: php

I try this:

```
echo nl2br($row['content']);
```

But what I get is:

> Hello everybody\n Good luck!

Why doesn't it convert the `\n`? the database is storing data as UTF-8.

In addition, I check it with a test string, and found out that if the string is with double quotes it doesn't work too.. I mean:

```
echo nl2br("Hello everybody\n Good luck");
```

Comment: What if you echo the raw output in a `<pre>`?

Comment: Inspect the input with var_dump.

Comment: I think you might have an encoding problem in PHP which means PHP binary does not recognise ASCII and UTF-8 characters. Though it could also be something elementary and just a confusion somewhere on how something works.

Comment: @Sammaye I checked the PHP file, database field.. it's all UTF-8.

Comment: You'll find that the actual text content will have escaped slashes, which does not work correctly with `nl2br`

Answer (score 0):

It should work but if you wish you can try `str_replace("\n","<br />")` instead of nl2br.

Comment: LOL. it doesn't work! haha, I think it doesn't recognize the `\n`

Comment: WORKING! do you have an explanation? :-) Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Everything in double quotes will be escaped by PHP. So, you have to escape that slash or have to use single quotes like '\n'.

Comment: This answer does not address the issue. nl2br effectively is `str_replace("\n","<br />")` so if nl2br doesn't work, neither will this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the text is being stored with an additional slash in your database. Use the `stripslashes` ([PHP doc here](https://www.php.net/stripslashes)) function on the text before `nl2br` ([PHP doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php))

```
$myText = "Hello\\nWorld"; //text from a database (with line breaks escaped)
stripslashes(nl2br($myText));
print $myText;
// Result: Hello<br>World
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have written to database `\n` as two characters, so it's not a "new line" character.

Try `echo str_replace('\n','<br />', $row['content'])`